# ResultSet always returns null, no matter what the changes are in JDBC/MySQL, Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have an application with a login form. What I want is simply retrieve the credentials of the user who logs in, i.e select the username and password from the login form and make a simple select query. However the resultset always return null, no matter what changes I made. I would like to ask what could be the problem? For the purpose of testing I have made 2 static variable in which I store the retrieved username and password (I will made the other alongside these fields in 1 class User but after I fix this). Here is the code: /The fields in the database are exactly like the ones written in the brackets of the getString() method/

```
package graphical_interface;
import business_logic.User;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    public Button loginB;
    public Button exitB;
    public TextField userinp;
    public TextField passinp;
    public Parent pr;
    public static String s1 = null;
    public static String s2 = null;
    @FXML
    private void closeApp() {
        Platform.exit();
    }
    String username = null;
    String password = null;
    @FXML
    private void checkB(){

            try {
                PreparedStatement pstmt2 = null;
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://remotemysql.com/CXcocPWj6l", "CXcocPWj6l", "czNrEV9umD");
                String query  = "select * from User where Username = ? and PassWord = ?";
                pstmt2.setString(1,userinp.getText());
                pstmt2.setString(2,passinp.getText());
                ResultSet valueExist = pstmt2.executeQuery(query);
                if(valueExist.next()){
                    s1 = valueExist.getString("Username");
                    s2 = valueExist.getString("PassWord");
                   // System.out.println(valueExist.getString("PassWord");
                }
                conn.close();
                System.out.println(s1);
                System.out.println(s2);

            } catch (Exception exp){
                System.out.println(exp.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the result set returns null, or did possibly `valueExists.next()` return `false`, meaning that no row matched? As an aside, storing unhashed passwords in your database is extremely unsafe. Please learn about password hash algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL syntax seems to be correct, so few questions: are you sure that the table contains the record you are finding for? Are you sure that "userinp.getText()" and "passinp.getText()" return something not null?

Finally two advice: use try with resource or at least use the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the columnLabel with columnIndex i.e. replace

```
if(valueExist.next()){
    s1 = valueExist.getString("Username");
    s2 = valueExist.getString("PassWord");
}
```

with

```
if(valueExist!=null && valueExist.next()){
    s1 = valueExist.getString(columnIndex-of-Username);
    s2 = valueExist.getString(columnIndex-of-PassWord);
}
```

where `columnIndex-of-Username` and `columnIndex-of-PassWord` are integer values holding the columnIndex of `Username` and `PassWord` respectively.

**Note**: the first column is 1, the second is 2, ...

If you have any typo in columnLabels, it may help fix your problem. Using `columnIndex` instead of `columnLabel` has another advantage of performance improvement (check https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaha/jdbcperf.htm)

Comment: Why do you suggest using the index instead of the column name here? The OP is using `select *`, so the order of columns is not immediately obvious. Selecting by index is therefor not a good idea, and referencing by name is advisable in that case, and as the where clause references columns `Username` and `Password` we can be sure they exist and can be referenced by that name. If a column with that name would not exist, a JDBC driver will throw a `SQLException`, not return `null`.

Comment: I maintain a JDBC driver and I am a member of the JSR-221 (JDBC 4) Expert Group, I think I know JDBC well enough. That link gives good hints or rules of thumb for **better performance** (and in the context of a specific IBM JDBC driver!). You just blanket suggest that accessing the column by index would somehow fix the problem of the OP. It wouldn't. You may want to explain why you think your answer addresses the problem of the OP.